# How can I make a request to all elements inside a form?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have a form, with many elements (inputs, selections, checkboxes etc..). How can I apply an action to all elements inside the form without explicitly doing it per element?

Here is my code (in Selenium IDE):

```
storeEval |
window.document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].id = 'myForm';
window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(window.document.myForm.getElementsByTagName('*')).getPropertyValue('background-color');
| result
```

I get an error: `[error] Threw an exception: document.myForm is undefined`

I tried to do this:

```
storeEval |
window.document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].id = 'myForm';
window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementById('myForm')).getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

It works correctly.

When I try to do this:

```
var myForm = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
var children = myForm.childNodes;
```

I get an error: `[error] Threw an exception: document.myForm is undefined`

Comment: I need to get back-ground color of all elements of form (by method getComputedStyle + getPropertyValue)

Comment: The best solution depends from what you're trying to do, which is not very clear.

Comment: In your code you are referring to `document.myForm`. It should be just `myForm`, since you stored an `HTMLFormElement` object inside `var myForm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Command: storeEval
Target : myForm = selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].childNodes; var colors = new Array(); for (i=0; i < myForm.length; i++) { colors[i] = window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(myForm[i]).getPropertyValue('background-color')}; colors.join()
Value  : result
```

JavaScript snippet `selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()` gets the window of your application.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to set an `id` attribute to your form tag, so you can easily identify it with JavaScript.

For example, if your form `id` is `myForm`, you could do this

```
var children = document.myForm.childNodes;
// or
var children = document.myForm.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

The first returns the list of *direct* descendants, while the second returns a list of *all* descendants.

**EDIT**: You can identify a form in many other ways than by `id`, but it could become hard. Try with `document.getElementsByTagName('form')`. This works well especially if you have only one form in your page.

Comment: big thaks to you, it's works, but in my form, I don't have id, only action and method (

Comment: can I give an id to my form by "window.document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].id = 'forma'" ? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes it is, but it doesn't make much sense. At this point you already identified your form. Just do something like: `var myForm = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]; var children = myForm.childNodes;`

Comment: Strange... works well for me. Please update your question with your relevant code.

Comment: window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementsByTagName('form')).getPropertyValue('background-color') [error] Threw an exception: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why would you want to do that, but in order to refer **all** children tags inside the form tag, you may try the following:

```css
#my_form * {
  color: #369
}
```

Yet if you'd like to only refer form-specific elements there's not that much of them, so you just specify them in a row:

```css
#my_form select, #my_form input, #my_form label, #my_form button {
  color: #369
}
```

**Edit**. If you want to refer all elements inside a form via javascript, **and** you're using jQuery framework (which I'd highly recommend), you may just use the same selectors:

```js
$('#my_form *').css( ... )
$('#my_form select, #my_form input, #my_form label, #my_form button').css( ... )
```

Comment: he wants a javascript solution